# Graphqlresolver for common subfield under different parent field type

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am new to graphql, I have requirement where multiple different types have the same field which I am fetching from downstream call, can you please suggest how I can write the graphqlresolver for this subfield?

```
{
  Type1 {
    title
    Field1
  },
  Type2 {
    Field1
  }
}
```

here Field1 value I will be getting I want to write resolver which will fetch value based on parent type also if the downstream support batch api how can i call api only once for type1 and type2 fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a single resolver function for `Field1` and add it to both the `Type1` and `Type2` types.

```
const Field1 = (parent,args,context) => …return Field1;

const Type1 = {
  title: (parent,args,context) => …return the title,
  Field1,
}

const Type2 = {
  Field1
}

const resolvers = {...Type1,...Type2}
```

Beware that this function will be called with a different `parent` variable depending on which type is being resolved.

You can't make GraphQL call your `Field1` function only once because the GraphQL server is stateless and the resolution of this field under different types happens independently of each other.

If you want to minimize resolution of an external API behind `Field1` then you will need to *cache* the results of that API call.